# upgrading python and mod_wsgi not helping apache stick to newer python

Tags: python, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I had a box with debian on it and python 2.6, I installed apache, mod_wsgi and configured everything and then realized by app is not compatible with python 2.6; so I installed python 2.7 from testing rep, updated-alternatives to make the new python the default one, installed django and apt-get installed libapache2-mid-wsgi and it seemed to install ok and restarted apache:

```
Unpacking libpython2.7 (from .../libpython2.7_2.7.2-8_i386.deb) ...
Preparing to replace libapache2-mod-wsgi 3.3-2 (using .../libapache2-mod-wsgi_3.3-4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libapache2-mod-wsgi ...
Setting up libpython2.7 (2.7.2-8) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-wsgi (3.3-4) ...
Restarting web server: apache2...
```

however, apache still uses the older version of python:

```
Exception Value:    

invalid syntax (views.py, line 14)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/home',
 '/home/portman']
```

what is it that I need to do to help mod_wsgi see the proper version of python?

Comment: 'Package: libapache2-mod-wsgi
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Installed-Size: 384
Source: mod-wsgi
Version: 3.3-2
Provides: httpd-wsgi
Depends: apache2, apache2.2-common, libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~), libpython2.6 (>= 2.6), python (>= 2.5), python (<< 2.7)
Filename: pool/main/m/mod-wsgi/libapache2-mod-wsgi_3.3-2_i386.deb
Package: libapache2-mod-wsgi
Source: mod-wsgi
Version: 3.3-4
Depends: apache2, apache2.2-common, libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~), libpython2.6 (>= 2.6), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), python (>= 2.6), python (<< 2.8)
Suggests: apache2-mpm-worker | apache2-mpm-event
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, needed to configure wsgi.load in mods-enabled to point to the right .so file